# Calculating velocity from a pressure distribution

Tags: pressure, velocity, bernoulli-equation

Using computational fluid dynamics I have calculated the pressure distribution over a streamlined body. I have access to the static, dynamic and total pressure seperately and assume that I can use Bernoulli's equation to calculate the velocity.

However, if Bernoulli's equation is given as:

$p_s+\frac{\rho V^2}{2}=p_t$

I can write the velocity $V$ as:

$V=\sqrt{\frac{2(p_t-p_s)}{\rho}}$

But this form does not seem to show the inverse proportionality between pressure and velocity that the equation is famous for.

What is the flaw in my reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in your reasoning is that you believe that pressure and velocity are said to be inversely proportional, $p=K/v$, by the law.

Instead, Bernoulli's law says that these two variables are in inverse *relationship* (but not "proportionality") which means that one of them is a *decreasing* function of the other, and you wrote what the function is. $p=K/v$ is *a* class of decreasing functions of $v$ but there are infinitely many other decreasing functions, too.